# TableView.reloadData() doesn't work after save data into core data entity

Tags: swift

I'm trying to insert a default record into my core data entity while the tableview first-time loaded and checked there's no data in the entity.
The data inserted just fine , but the `reloadData()` didn't work, after navigate to other view and navigate back to the view the data appears. no matter the `reloadData()` in or out of the `.save()` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let cateContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    let categoryRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Category")

    categoryArray = (try! cateContext.executeFetchRequest(categoryRequest)) as! [Category]

    if categoryArray.count == 0 {

        let category = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: cateContext) as! Category

        category.sno = "1"
        category.category = "General"
        category.locate = false

        do {

            try cateContext.save()
            self.categoryTableView.reloadData()

        } catch let saveError as NSError {

            print("Saving Error : \(saveError.localizedDescription)")

        }


    }
    //self.categoryTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You need to fetch the new data and then reload your tableview

Comment: Yes! It works ! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are calling `self.categoryTableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad()` method it will not reload your tableView twice. You need to call `self.categoryTableView.reloadData()` **after** you have checked if entity existed **again**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!